# PHP Laravel Blade {{{ $name or 'Default' }}} printing 1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

De acordo com a documentação do Laravel

```
{{{ $name or 'Default' }}}
```

deveria se comportar como

```
if(isset($name))
   echo $name
else
   echo 'Default'
```

ou

```
echo isset($title) ? $title : 'Default'
```

Mas está retornando `1` como se fosse um `true`.

Agora estou usando `{{ isset($title) ? $title : 'Default' }}` e está funcionando, mas gostaria de entender o que acontece na primeira versão, alguém sabe dizer porque recebo `1`?

Comment: Olá @Vitor. Coloque a sua questão em português, está no **SOpt**. Obrigado.

Comment: No primeiro exemplo você usa a variável `$nome` e no segundo a variável `$title`.

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar `{{ $name or 'Default' }}` (com apenas duas chaves). Aparentemente do jeito que seu código está, o valor retornado é o valor lógico da expressão "$name or 'Default'", que no caso retorna true pois o PHP interpreta uma string não vazia como verdadeiro.

Comment: Copiei e colei, troquei a variavel $name  assim: `{{ $title or 'Default' }}` retornou 1 do mesmo jeito :)

Comment: Qual sua versão do Laravel? Pelo que andei procurando, o operador `or` foi descontinuado na versão 5.5, conforme comentado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284344/ternary-in-laravel-blade/37463931#comment73551300_37463931). Se a versão do seu PHP for >= 7, pode usar `{{ $variable ?? "default" }}`. Se for menor, use `{{ $variable ? $variable  : "Default" }}`.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, é isso ... minha versão é a ultima, instalei laravel ontem, OBRIGADAO CARA !

Comment: Por nada, cara!

Comment: @VictorHugo Se o problema foi resolvido, vc pode aceitar a resposta, veja [**aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como fazê-lo. Isso é útil pois indica para futuros visitantes e demais usuários que esta solução funcionou.